# format string to a datetime in a datagrid vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("tarea", "Tarea")
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("horas", "Horas")
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("descripcion", "Descripcion")
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("fecha", "Fecha")
    dg_datos.Columns("fecha").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"


    dg_datos.Rows.Add("Ada Lovelace", "1", "desc.1", "10/11/2002")
```

I think I did not correctly specify the date format

Comment: This covers the formatting issue but filtering still isn't going to work because you still haven't addressed how to get the data into the grid via a `DataTable` in order to enable filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't format a `String`, as I already said. Just as numeric format specifiers only work on numbers, date format specifiers only work on `Dates`. The immediate fix is to use an actual `Date`:

```vb
dg_datos.Rows.Add("Ada Lovelace", "1", "desc.1", #11/10/2002#)
```

That is using a `Date` literal. Note that `Date` literals are ALWAYS in the format `#M/dd/yyyy#`. So I have switched the day and month values in your example. Now that you have an actual `Date`, date format specifiers will actually work.

You can get a `Date` value in various different ways. In places where you would use literals for `Strings` or numbers, you can use a `Date` literal too. If you want to construct a `Date` though, there are numerous ways. For example, you might use `Date.Now` for the current date and time, `Date.Today` to get the current date with the time zeroed. You can also use a constructor to build a `Date` from individual numbers for each component.

Comment: Hi @John, I change and the work good, but in the filter, he said me the fecha column doesn't exist

Comment: @Pablo, this question doesn't address anything about the filtering issue, as I already stated in a comment on the question.

Comment: @Pablo, actually, I notice that you're adding numbers as `Strings` too. If that second column is the number of hours then it should actually contain a number, i.e. `dg_datos.Rows.Add("Ada Lovelace", 1, "desc.1", #11/10/2002#)`.